# Separate Columns for each variable

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am facing an issue where I must retrieve all the possible locations for a product and organize them in a column. In our warehouse, a product can occupy multiple locations, and when I extract the data is organized like so:

```
SKID      LOCATION
----      --------
A         S1
A         S2
A         S3
B         S4
B         S5
C         S6
```

I would like to organize it so that locations are organized into separate columns.

```
SKID      LOCATION1      LOCATION2      LOCATION3
----      ---------      ---------      ---------
A         S1             S2             S3
B         S4             S5             -
C         S6             -              -
```

How can this be done, if it can be done at all?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: Hmmm I believe this will only allow me to transpose the location as a column, and with 44k locations I do not think it will help me. I poorly formulated my question I realize now.

Comment: Is there a hard limit to the number of locations that can be associated with a skid? Note that just pivoting will give you one column for each instance of location across all the data (S1 column, S2 column, ....) etc... I think to get it how you want you'd have to pivot, then do a conditional aggregation to consolidate with the number of column equal to the max location:skid. Also note you probably shouldn't do this. I'd really interrogate the requirement and make sure this is what's really needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you closer -

```
SELECT
    SKID,
    LISTAGG(LOCATION,',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                SKID,LOCATION
        ) as location
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            'A' AS SKID,
            'S1' AS LOCATION
        FROM
            DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT
            'A' AS SKID,
            'S2' AS LOCATION
        FROM
            DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT
            'A' AS SKID,
            'S3' AS LOCATION
        FROM
            DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT
            'B' AS SKID,
            'S4' AS LOCATION
        FROM
            DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT
            'B' AS SKID,
            'S5' AS LOCATION
        FROM
            DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT
            'C' AS SKID,
            'S6' AS LOCATION
        FROM
            DUAL
    )
GROUP BY
    SKID;
```

Output -

```
SKID,LOCATION
A,S1,S2,S3
B,S4,S5
C,S6
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the maximum number of columns you want in the result set, you can do this using conditional aggregation or `pivot`:

```
select skid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then location end) as location_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then location end) as location_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then location end) as location_3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by skid order by location) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by skid;
```

If you don't know the maximum, then dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`), `listagg()`, nested tables, or JSON are some alternatives.